# Error: unknown option: -M while using module option of maven-jdeps-plugin

Tags: java, maven, java-9, jdeps, maven-jdeps-plugin

I found the [`module`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jdeps-plugin/jdkinternals-mojo.html#module) attribute on the official documentation of the `maven-jdeps-plugin` which states that

> Show module containing the package
>
> - Type: boolean
> - Since: JDK 1.9.0
> - Required: No
> - User Property: jdeps.module
> - Default: false

Trying to make use of it with the current minimal `pom.xml` as follows:-

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jdeps-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <apiOnly>false</apiOnly>
                <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
                <module>true</module>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jdkinternals</goal> <!-- verify main classes -->
                        <goal>test-jdkinternals</goal> <!-- verify test classes -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The build of my project(named *sparkjdk9*) on executing

```
mvn clean install
```

results into these logs:-

> ```
> [INFO] --- maven-jdeps-plugin:3.1.0:jdkinternals (default) @ sparkjdk9 ---
> [INFO] 
> Error: unknown option: -M
> Usage: jdeps <options> <path ...>]
> use -h, -?, -help, or --help for a list of possible options
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time: 2.649 s
> [INFO] Finished at: ...
> [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/44M
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jdeps-plugin:3.1.0:jdkinternals (default) on project sparkjdk9: 
> [ERROR] Exit code: 2
> [ERROR] Command line was: /bin/sh -c '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jdeps' '-M' '.../sparkjdk9/target/classes'
> ```

Looking further for similar flag in [`jdeps`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeps.htm#JSWOR690) tool, I could see the error is justified since there is no such flag `-M` in its usage.

**Q. What is the use of this attribute and how can it be used?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-jdeps-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/jdeps/AbstractJDepsMojo.java#L322

The `-M` used to be the module parameter, but it seems like it has been renamed to `-m`/`--module` in the meantime.

***Update*** : This should be resolved with 3.1.1 release of the Maven JDeps Plugin as followed by the tracker](See https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-jdeps-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/jdeps/AbstractJDepsMojo.java#L322

The `-M` used to be the module parameter, but it seems like it has been renamed to `-m`/`--module` in the meantime.

***Update*** : This should be resolved with 3.1.1 release of the Maven JDeps Plugin as followed [by the tracker.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MJDEPS/issues/MJDEPS-11)

Comment: Not sure where to raise this as a bug to add to the tracker for the plugin to fix. Also, `-m <module-name>/  --module <module-name> ` in tool I can see are used to specify the root module for analysis..would this also need a change in `Type` pf the attribute? (not aware of what was the initial construct used)

Comment: That would be issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJDEPS